# Arduino Client.print insert a variable

Tags: arduino

I am trying to insert a variable inside a client.print on my arduino script but cannot get my script to work, my guess is that my variable is declared as double, tried to change it to char but my output is voltage and i need the decimal points, any suggestions?

```
double variable;

 client.println("<head> <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; url=http://localhost/add.php?param="+ variable +" /></head>");
```

my error

```
 blink1:57: error: invalid operands of types 'const char [97]' and 'double' to binary 'operator+'

  client.println("<head> <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; url=http://localhost/add.php?param="+ variable +"' /></head>");
```

Comment: [How do I print multiple variables in a string?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/176/how-do-i-print-multiple-variables-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Arduino String object it's as simple as:

```
client.println("<head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; url=http://localhost/add.php?param="+ String(variable) +" /></head>");
```

As a side note, try not to calculate using floating-point types on Arduino, the processor lack hardware support for them and they are really slow.